# redefinition of comparison operators of enums

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, operator-overloading

Why following operator overloadings allowed?

```
enum class e { a, b, };

constexpr
bool operator == (e l, e r)
{ return l != r; }

constexpr
bool operator != (e l, e r)
{ return !(l == r); }

static_assert(e::a == e::b, "==");
static_assert(e::a != e::a, "!=");
```

[Live example (C++11)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/692c48aba939061f).

[Live example (C++03)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4ee493166b88a0e).

I always think about `enum`s as about built-in types. I can't redefine `operator ==` for pointer to my custom type (but I want!), but can do this for pair of `enum` of the same type. However both have built-in versions of `operator ==` and `operator !=`.

What is a possible purpose of such (seems wrong) thing? How one can use it profitly?

Comment: what is wrong about it?

Comment: I mean it doesnt make much sense to define the operators like this, but otherwise it looks completely fine to me

Comment: @tobi303 I always think about `enum`s as about built-in types. I can't redefine `operator ==` for, say, `int`, but can do it for `enum`.

Comment: I guess you're wondering about the possible recursion issue?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg There no recursion. Second operator is not forward-declared.

Comment: From [this operator overloading reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators): "When an operator appears in an expression, and at least one of its operands has a class type or an **enumeration type**, then overload resolution is used to determine the user-defined function to be called..." (emphasis mine).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Defenitely there is a need to restrict the rule in such a way, that two operands to `operator ==` must not be of the same `enum` type simultaneously.

Comment: As for the recursion, your `==` operator calls the `!=` operator which calls the `==` operator... But I'm actually unsure if the original `!=` operator will be the overloaded function, since it's before your `!=` operator function is declared.

Comment: And why should it not be allowed to compare two values of the same enumeration? It kind of makes no sense otherwise. It's like comparing two string, it would make no sense in not allowing one to not compare one value of one type, to another value of the same type.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg [`constexpr` virtual machine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/692c48aba939061f) does not caught in an endless loop

Comment: @JoachimPileborg `why should it not be allowed to compare two values of the same enumeration` I didn't say it. I say about redefinition of `operator ==` and `operator !=`.

Comment: I still don't understand what the problem is, why should it not be allowed to overload those operators? Should it not be allowed only for enumerations? Can you please edit your question to make it a little clearer?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Just a minute.

Comment: And even through non-class enumerations can be converted to and from integers, they are still a custom type, not actual integers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here, it seems, is that you think (unscoped) enumerations are equal to integers. Like I said in my comment, enumeration values can be *converted* from or to integers, but they are still a custom type for which you can overload operators.

See e.g. [this unscoped enumeration reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum#Unscoped_enumeration), and [this reference on implicit conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast) (especially the sections about [integral promotion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast#Integral_promotion) and [integral conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast#Integral_conversions)).

Comment: Which other *custom type* `T` have built-in `operator == (T, T)` and `operator != (T, T)`? (I think they are not *custom*).

Comment: @Orient Enums do not have build in `operator ==` . They have a build in `operator int()`, and `operator ==(int, int)` gets called when you try to compare 2 enums.

Comment: @Orient It doesn't have a *built-in* comparison operator, not the same way `int` does. Again: Enumeration are custom types! See also [this post with a quote from the creator of C++](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/289588-c-enum-comparison/#entry2825649).

Comment: Code invariants holds for scoped enums as well.

Comment: @rozina For brevity see last edit (`class` now uncommented). As you can see implicit cast to `std::underlying_type_t` is prohibited now, but still no one `static_assert`ion failed and code is well-formed.

Answer (score 1):

Enums are user-defined types as much as structs are, or classes, or unions.

Your code works because one operator cannot see the other at declaration, so one of the calls to `==` or `!=` calls the default one and compares them as integral types.

Sure, it provides a default `==`, but you can override it if you want.